# A dynamically resizing shiny textAreaInput box?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make a textAreaInput box in shiny that spans 100% of my webpage and resizes when the browser is min/maximised. I can make a simple textInput with this behavior by supplying the argument width = 100%. Supplying the same argument to textAreaInput does not produce the same behavior even though width has the same description on the [textInput](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/textInput.html) and [textAreaInput](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/textAreaInput.html) man pages. Is this desired behavour or a bug?

A minimal working example -

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
    #UI
    ui = fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
            column(12,
                textAreaInput("big_box", "Big box", value = "", width = '100%', rows = 5, resize = "both")
            )
        ), 
        fluidRow(
            column(12,
                textInput("long_box", "Long box", value = "", width = '100%')
            )
        )
    ),
    #Server
    server = function(input, output) {
    }
)
```

Example output -

[image]

Cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`textAreaInput` was recently added to Shiny in version 14, it seems that it is a bug cause by the class `shiny-input-container`. In shiny.css we can find:

> ```
> /* Limit the width of inputs in the general case. */
>
> .shiny-input-container:not(.shiny-input-container-inline) {
>   width: 300px;
>   max-width: 100%;
> }
> ```

The simplest workaround is to create a new function based on the original without  the class `shiny-input-container`. Below is the new function.

```R
library(shiny)

#based on Shiny textAreaInput
textAreaInput2 <- function (inputId, label, value = "", width = NULL, height = NULL, 
    cols = NULL, rows = NULL, placeholder = NULL, resize = NULL) 
{
    value <- restoreInput(id = inputId, default = value)
    if (!is.null(resize)) {
        resize <- match.arg(resize, c("both", "none", "vertical", 
            "horizontal"))
    }
    style <- paste("max-width: 100%;", if (!is.null(width)) 
        paste0("width: ", validateCssUnit(width), ";"), if (!is.null(height)) 
        paste0("height: ", validateCssUnit(height), ";"), if (!is.null(resize)) 
        paste0("resize: ", resize, ";"))
    if (length(style) == 0) 
        style <- NULL
    div(class = "form-group", 
        tags$label(label, `for` = inputId), tags$textarea(id = inputId, 
        class = "form-control", placeholder = placeholder, style = style, 
        rows = rows, cols = cols, value))
}

shinyApp(
    #UI
    ui = fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
            column(12,
                textAreaInput2("big_box2", "Big box", value = "", width = '100%', rows = 5, resize = "both")
            )
        ), 
        fluidRow(
            column(12,
                textInput("long_box", "Long box", value = "", width = '100%')
            )
        )
    ),
    #Server
    server = function(input, output) {
    }
)
```

Answer (score 15):

A simpler workaround is to set the height and width parameters to the parent element, using shiny::tagAppendAttributes function.

For example:

```
 textAreaInput("big_box", "Big box", value = "", rows = 5, resize = "both") %>%
     shiny::tagAppendAttributes(style = 'width: 100%;')
```

Answer (score 11):

Or you could just override the css by using a header tag within your ui function e.g:

```
tags$style(HTML("                  
  .shiny-input-container:not(.shiny-input-container-inline) {
  width: 100%;
}"))
```